# Java/Android Writing and reading from 2 different sockets using objectstream

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm making an app that sends objects through sockets (A group chat project). First an AsynchTask starts a server process that continues to listen on port 10000 using objectinputstream. Whenever a message is entered from the main thread it is passed into another AsynchTask that is a client process that builds and object and sends it out to other processes Asynch server task. The port it sends on is NOT 10000. I'm getting a blocking issue when trying to send an object. I've read that objectoutputstream needs to be called first however I only see that discussed when reading and writing on same port. Is there a way to continuously listen on a port for objects and write objects only when necessary?

```html
private class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<ServerSocket, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ServerSocket... sockets) {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = sockets[0];
            
            while (true) {
                try (
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                ) {
                    Log.i("I got Here", "I'm open");


                    Object o = in.readObject();
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    in.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
```

and the client task

```html
private class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... msgs) {
            try {

                int remotePort = 11108;
                int i;
                for(i = 0; i<5;i++){
                    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),
                            remotePort);

                    String msgToSend = msgs[0];
                
                    counter = counter++;
                    GroupMessageRequest m = new GroupMessageRequest();
                    m.id = Float.parseFloat(counter +"."+msgs[1]);
                    m.message = msgToSend;
                    m.sender = msgs[1];
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    out.flush();
                    out.writeObject(m);

                    out.close();
                    socket.close();
                    Log.e("Sent Message", "sent Message network");

                    remotePort = remotePort + 4;
                }


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ClientTask UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ClientTask socket IOException");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The socket setup is strange due to a "hack" being used to have 5 emulators behave the way I need it too for testing. I know the sockets aren't the issue I just can't get these objectstreams to do what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You must create the `ObjectOutputStream` right after creating the connected `Socket`, before engaging in any other blocking operations whatsoever. You should handle each accepted `Socket` in a separate thread, and construct its `ObjectInputStream` in the `run()` method of that thread,not in the thread which is executing the `accept()` loop, so that any problems creating it don't affect other clients. `counter = counter++;` is dubious.

Comment: So I'm calling this AsynchTask in the body of my code once to start this server thread. You recommend I instead call the socket accept in a loop and when a socket is accepted start an AsynchTask for that instance and call operations from then on? Can I pass an open socket into an AsynchTask? Thank you!